# OAuth Authentication - Is it possible to keep bearer token active if the user is active

Tags: owin, mobile-application, webapi

Is it possible to keep bearer token active if the user is active

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the user info in Redis(For multiple servers to share this info), or you can put it in token directly,if the user info is very little.